# Create a class using objects of another class

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to create a class `Line` which consists of two objects of another class `Point`:

```
class Point
{
    double x, y, z;

    public:
    // constructor from 3 values
    Point(double x, double y, double z);

    // copy constructor
    Point(const Point &p);

    // method display
    void display();
};

// constructor from 3 values
Point::Point(double x, double y, double z)
: x(x), y(y), z(z)
{}

// copy constructor
Point::Point(const Point &p)
: x(p.x), y(p.y), z(p.z)
{}

void Point::display()
{
    cout << "Point(" << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << ")\n";
}


class Line
{
    Point pnt1, pnt2;

    public:
    // constructor from 2 points
    Line(Point& pnt1, Point& pnt2);

    // method display line
    void display();
};

// constructor from 2 points
Line::Line(Point& pnt1_, Point& pnt2_)
: pnt1(pnt1_), pnt2(pnt2_)
{}

// method display line
void Line::display()
{
    cout << "Line(Point(" << pnt1.x << ", " << pnt1.y << ", " << pnt1.z << ")" << ", Point(" << pnt2.x << ", " << pnt2.y << ", " << pnt2.z << ")\n";
}
```

And here is the main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include "geometryitems.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // initialise object Point
    cout << endl << "Point initialisation:" << endl;

    Point pnt = Point(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    cout << "pnt = "; pnt.display();

    Point pnt2 = Point(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    cout << "pnt2 = "; pnt2.display();

    // initialising object Line
    cout << "Line initialisation:" << endl;

    Line line = Line(pnt, pnt2);
    line.display();

    return 0;
}
```

The points work fine but the line gives me errors that `class "Point" has no members named a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2`.

How to create class `Line` using objects of class `Point`? Thank you.

**Update**

I have updated the code using the copy constructor but it still talking about private `x, y, z`. Any ideas?

Comment: Declare `Point`members as `public`, and use `x`, `y`, `z`. `a1`, `b1` etc. are not members of `Point`.

Comment: There's no such **public** members

Comment: Your constructor for the `line` class is the problem. Change it

Comment: I do not want to make them public. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a quick and dirty solution with getters for your private data members.

```
   double getX() { return x ; };
   double getY() { return y ; };
   double getZ() { return z ; };
```

I changed as well the Line cstor.

```
   // constructor from 2 points
   Line::Line(Point& _pnt1, Point& _pnt2)
   : pnt1(_pnt1), pnt2(_pnt2)
   {}
```

And changed the call to these getters in your cout.

```
   cout << "Line(Point(" << pnt1.getX() << ", " << pnt1.getY() << ", " << pnt1.getZ() << ")" << ", Point(" << pnt2.getX() << ", " << pnt2.getY() << ", " << pnt2.getZ() << ")\n";
```

Check it out: http://ideone.com/aHmin9

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check that.

Answer (score 2):

Add a copy-constructor to your `Point` class:

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point(const Point& p)
        : x(p.x), y(p.y), z(p.z)
        {}

    ...
};
```

Then you can use that for the `Line` constructor:

```
Line::Line(const Point& p1, const Point& p2)
    : pnt1(p1), pnt2(p2)
{}
```

The `Line` class don't need separate point variables `a1`, `b1`, `c1` etc. And of course the actual `Point` objects don't have member variables named like that, which you try to access. Also note that the member variable in `Point` are private, you the `Line::display` function can't access them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where should I insert the copy-constructor?

Comment: It says `expected unqualified id before const`

Comment: It says `In file included from testGI.cpp:3:0: geometryitems.cpp:116:1: error: prototype for 'Line::Line(const Point&, const Point&)' does not match any in class 'Line'
In file included from geometryitems.cpp:2:0,from testGI.cpp:3:
geometryitems.h:97:7: error: candidates are: Line::Line(const Line&)
geometryitems.h:105:5: error: Line::Line(Point&, Point&)`

Comment: @Alexandr It's because I made the arguments `const`, you have to change the declaration or remove the `const`.

Comment: I get many different errors. Can you write completely both classes in your answer - I do not know how to implement your solution in my program.

Comment: @Alexandr I'm sorry but I will not write a complete solution for you, that's not really a good way to learn. Instead you should look at the small example I have in my answer, and read the error messages to try and understand what they mean, and figure it out yourself. That way you will truly have learned yourself, not just copy-paste some code without understanding what it does.

Comment: I have managed to implement it but it still gives me that `x, y, z` are private.

Comment: @Alexandr Then don't use them from the `Line` class! Instead you might want to call the `Point::display` function from `Line::display`. Or better yet, implement output operators for the two classes (i.e. overload `operator<<`).

Comment: It does not solve my problem, since I am going to use these points in other methods of `Line`.

Answer (score 0):

Class point has member x,y,z instead of a1,b1,c1.
It should be

```
void Line::display()
{
    cout << "Line(Point(" << pnt1.x << ", " << pnt1.y << ", " << pnt1.z << ")" << ",  Point(" << pnt2.x << ", " << pnt2.y << ", " << pnt2.z << ")\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Question has the solution in it : class "Point" has no members named a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2.

So your class Contains x, y and z instead....Try to print it using x, y and z

Make sure the members are public or use getters and setters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The members are private and I do not want to make them public. I will check the second thing.